# Why is Index being graphed and not country? Using Matplotlib Horizontal Bar Graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm pretty new to all of this. I've been looking online how to change my y-ticks to represent a column that I wanted to initially graph.

Anyway, I have a dataframe that I created by using a SQL command...it's called eastasia_pac. The columns are `index` (although apparently it's not really a column), `country`, `region`, `no.female_borrowers`.

My dataframe looks like this:

[image: click this link for dataframe]

I want to graph my dataframe so...

```
y = eastasia_pac.country
eastasia_pac.plot.barh()
plt.barh(y, width= 0.3, height= 0.8)
plt.xlabel("Number of Female Active Borrowers")
plt.ylabel("Country")
plt.yticks(rotation= 90)
plt.title("East Asia and the Pacific: No. of Female Active Borrowers")
```

It came out like this:

[image: img]

For some reason, the index is on the y-axis and not country and I don't know how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `matplotlib` plots according the index of a specified `dataframe`. You can solve this by either setting the index of the data or by overwriting the values.

**Overwrite method:**

```
# I'm assuming this is what's creating your plot
eastasia_pac.plot.barh()

# Set your ticks
plt.yticks(eastasia_pac.country, rotation= 90)

# Set your labels
plt.xlabel("Number of Female Active Borrowers")
plt.ylabel("Country")
```

**Set Index:**

```
# Create your bar plot using country as an index
eastasia_pac.set_index("country").plot.barh()

# Set your labels
plt.xlabel("Number of Female Active Borrowers")
plt.ylabel("Country")
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks so much for this!!

Comment: So... this is what ended up happening:
ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units:
Name: country, dtype: object
Is there a concept I'm missing?

Comment: However the set index method did work! Maybe the overwrite method may work for a future problem...thank you very much Yaakov! Greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Could you share a sample of your data? `print(df.head(2))` I'm curious as how to solve this too. @joy

Comment: Absolutely. How do I add a screenshot to a comment? I'll actually edit it into the question itself @yaakov

Comment: Easier if you paste the head... @joy